# finding clicked id deep in document using jquery

Tags: jquery, json, click, alert, attr

I'm going to use the text from the jquery example, For example, consider the HTML:

```
<lots of divs to get to here>

<div id="#targetid_0">
  Click here
</div>
<div id="#targetid_1">
  Trigger the handler
</div>
```

I have a series of questions that are plaguing me...

Assuming that I click on 'Click Here' or 'Trigger the Handler':

1. If I'm assigning a value via the attr(targetid_x,JSON.ID), how can I use alert to show me that value? It's driving me nuts!
2. How do I find out the specific clicked #tag? (sort of related to question 1).

I'd like to see if this can be accomplished with Event Delegation or at least without classes.

Halp!

Comment: Did your HTML example get swallowed when you posted this?

Comment: I do not understand your question at all.

Comment: No, this is html. I need help trying to figure out the jquery commands to pull the specific ids and their attr out of a click event.

Comment: you need to provide a click handler which takes a single parameter, which will be the click event itself.  You can then search through the click event for the originating id.  Look up javascript click events for more information.

Comment: @NickLarsen, Thanks for pointing in the direction. 
Something like this?
$('.classNearTopOfLineage').click(function(event){
// Do something here
alert($(this)-something to tell me the id of the clicked item);
});

Comment: If it helps, there are multiple areas to receive clicks on the single page, and each is in various levels of nested divs, which is why I'm throwing an attribute on them from a DB using JSON, and I need to pull those .data points to request additional data from the DB.

Comment: `id` attributes should not have `#` at the start of them. That's only for use in selectors.

Comment: @Bobince, I've tried it both ways. no difference. My results are below. I'm an epic fail on trying to dig into the document and pull out the clicked id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('div').click(function() {
    $(this).attr('id');
});
```

Comment: so, should alert($(this).attr('id')); put something up in an alert box? Because it doesn't.

Here's my function:

$('.section1').click(function(event){
 var tmp =$(this).attr('id');
 alert (tmp);
 });

I even tried it as alert ($(this).attr('id')); <= empty alert box.

Comment: I'm not a jquery expert, but i don't think you need the "event" in your function. Try taking that out. Also try putting something like "test" in the alert box just to make sure that works.

Comment: Oh also when declaring variables i've had some trouble with this. Try doing var tmp = ($(this).attr('id'));

Comment: re:event, good point, that was inadvertantly left in from one of my permutations and research. Thank you.
lol, I'm getting results, but just as perplexing...
declaring: var tmp = ($(this).attr('id'));........alert("[o]"+$(this)[0]); // gives [o][object HTMLDivElement].......alert("attr"+$(this).attr('id')); //yields attr and nothing else........alert("just tmp"+tmp); //yields just tmp and nothing else..........This seems so easy, yet it's been killing me for days. i'm using jquery 1.4.1, btw. but I jsut switched today, and there hasn't been any change in results. I'm defeated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('div[id]').click(function(){
  alert(this.id);
  return false;
});
```

This adds an event listener to all divs that have an id.
The `return false;` part stops propagation. Thus if you have nested divs that have id's only the bottom(inner) one will show the alert, and then stops the event bubbling.

Comment: lolz, just noticed this is a year old question :)) I don't know how I got here :))